# Does Oracle Clob change the encoding of the data?

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, encoding, utf-8

I insert some Chinese content into my Oracle as CLOB and when I retrieve it in Python it seems nearly the same but especially the Chinese content seems to be slightly different.

This is UTF-8 and everything is checked in Python Debugger :

```
What goes in ?   "\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87" 
What comes out ? "\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\xbf\xbf"
```

1. Does CLOB change the encoding of the data that is very similar to UTF-8?
2. It still appears Chinese font but not all characters are same?
3. Is there anyway to enforce UTF-8 for CLOB?

And why is that I do not get into any of these issues when I use varchar in MSSQL? Is varchar just going to dump the stream of bytes as is without worrying about encoding? Everything works fine out of the box. I expect this, because I don't think DB should worry about encodings. Why is CLOB different?

My Oracle Charset is WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: What is the database character set used in Oracle and SQL Server? Did you define the column as `varchar` or `nvarchar` in SQL Server? In my experience encoding issues very often occur _before_ the data is sent to the database (e.g. HTML input forms, URL encoding etc)

Comment: MSSQL works fine and it has VARCHAR . Oracle datatype for the same column is CLOB . I am checking this @ Python Level , so it appears that everything is fine until saving to DB and the fact that it works fine in MSSQL but not in Oracle makes me think its something to do with Oracle CLOB . Does VARCHAR need to have a character set or does it just dump byte by byte whatever is the input  ?

Comment: *Every* character column (char, varchar, nvarchar, clob) has "a character set". In Oracle you define this when you create the instance. In SQL Server you define this when you create the database. Whether or not you can correctly save Chinese characters depends on the character set that the column uses.

Comment: I updated my Charset is there a way I could get UTF-8 bytes sensible ? I don't really see we do anything in Python so far that could change the data .

Comment: `WE8MSWIN1252` is a single-byte characterset. There is no way you can store multi-byte characters there. You have to change the character set in Oracle. Unfortunately this cannot be done "online". You need to dump your database, create a new database (=instance in Oracle) with the AL32UTF8 character set and then reload your dump.

Comment: Okay really helpful pointer . Let me reassess the situation :) I need to understand this a bit better as well .

Comment: If you can move this as an answer I would chose as the right answer ? Might help others as well .